# How to read from Deflate64 zip files in code in .NET?

Tags: .net, zip

I have a zip file compressed using Deflate64 method.
Neither the standard .NET ZipArchive (*The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.*) nor the Ionic Zip library (*Entry XXX uses an unsupported compression method (0x09, Deflate64)*) are able to decompress it.

Is there a way to do it in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

SecureBlackbox library (https://www.eldos.com/SecureBlackbox/) supports Deflate64 decompression, however it is commercial.

As far as I know it is the only solution for .NET at the moment, so do not consider my answer as a shameless advertisement :)